# How to close winform window after button_click event

Tags: c#, events, checkbox

I have program in Winfroms. I use a lot of check boxes to pick my options. And there is main button1 to click after options choosing. Everything works, I click on it, everything is generated right, but my winforms window still stays and doesn't go away. I need to click on exit mark. Is it possible to run and exit program after button1 click?

My code of button click event:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var header = File.ReadAllText(@"dir/header");
    var footer = File.ReadAllText(@"dir/footer");
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendLine(header);
    if (checkBox1.CheckState == CheckState.Checked) sb.AppendLine(@"\include{chap2}");
    if (checkBox2.CheckState == CheckState.Checked) sb.AppendLine(@"\include{chap3}");
    sb.AppendLine(footer);
    File.WriteAllText(@"dir/final", sb.ToString());
```

I found tutorials about this problem, but they all have the same problem. You need to click the exit mark and only then you can get out of winform window.

Comment: Eh, if `button1` is on the *main* form, just close the form? `Close()`?

Comment: lol thanks :) fast answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If the button is in the main form you can simply use [Close()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.close%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to
   exit the program

   ```
   this.Close();
   ```
2. If you're going to exit the program from another form, you have to
   use [Application.Exit()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157894%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
3. There's another way of closing the application called
   [Environment.Exit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx); something like a force close which as MSDN says:

> Terminates this process and returns an exit code to the operating
>   system.